Unable to tag or add the response message as a part of the conversation thread from the bot to the request from the user in skype
I am using botbuilder sdk for developing the skype bot and when the user sends any thing to the bot the bot responds but the response is not a part of the conversation thread created by the user.
const replyActivity = {type: "message",text: params.message,recipient: context.activity.recipient,serviceUrl: context.activity.serviceUrl,conversation: { isGroup: true, id: context.activity.conversation.id, conversationType: context.activity.type, name: context.activity.name },replyToId: context.activity.id,};

      await context.sendActivity(replyActivity);

Here in the above code , i am sending the reply activity object as the response for the request from the user
Even after adding the replyToId parameter its not getting added as a response to the request from the user.
